# OneDrive is not working in SharePoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, onedrive-for-business

I have followed below Microsoft article for set up Microsoft OneDrive in a SharePoint Server on-premises environment (SharePoint 2016).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sites/set-up-onedrive-for-business

After the setup is complete, "OneDrive" is available in app launcher as mentioned in the above article, however, it is redirecting to a blank page like https://mysite.domain.com/personal/user/_layouts/15/onedrive.aspx.

Are there any additional steps required to get the OneDrive to work in SharePoint 2016?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the followings and let us know the result:

1. Turn off anti-virus software and firewall.
2. Turn off proxy server if there is any.
3. Try to connect to different networks.
4. Reset [Internet Explorer settings](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/923737/how-to-reset-internet-explorer-settings), then try to navigate to your OneDrive for Business to check the outcome.
5. Perform a clean boot to your computer.

---

If the problem still exists after the above troubleshooting, there are many reasons why OneDrive is not working. So, I need to know exactly what went wrong via USL reports. Please kindly follow the steps below to locate the error message in the ULS report let us work further.

1.[Download ULS Viewer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44020).

2.Open ULS Viewer and You will see the following screen.

[image]

3.This green button will log your SharePoint 2016 ULS reports in real time.

[image]

4.Please click this button and use the default log storage location.

[image]

5.Down below you can see the real-time logs now.

[image]

6.This is the pause button. If you want to restart the logging, just click the green button again. Now you have mastered the basic application of this log viewer. Next let's find the log that went wrong.

[image]

7.Exit the page, then start logging, and re-enter the page. After a minute or two, press pause to stop logging.

8.In ULS Logs, Find out if there is some error message about the page. You can use Search->Find->enter keywords about this page to filter the Logs.

10.View all messages about this page. And share the related error messages which will help me to analyze the problem better. Please note that if there is any private information about you, please code it.

Comment: Hi Karley, thanks for your response. We found the root cause of the issue, i.e., "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\Next\odbnext\en-us" folder is missing in SharePoint servers. This folder has related script files like "odbonedrive.resx.js" and "odbonedriveapp.resx.js". If we copy this folder from other SharePoint server we have to this new server, then OneDrive starts working. This SharePoint 2016 server is newly built using latest patches. Do you know which package or update is required to get these required files?

Comment: Someone had also encountered this problem, it seems that you need to install Language dependent PU, you can try it.

Answer (score 0):

Someone had also encountered this problem, it seems that you need to install [Language dependent PU](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51492), you can try it.